# SQL increment on click (using ajax)

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, increment

I'm working on a simple button that will allows to increment a line in my table. Thanks to AJAX, when the button +1 is clicked, it is replaced by a -1 button. But the problem occurs when I click once on +1, then -1 and a second time on +1.

This is what i'm having :

```
vote = 0
click on "+1"
 vote = 1
click on "-1"
 vote = 0
click on "+1"
 vote = 2
click on "-1"
 vote = 0
click on "+1"
 vote = 3
```

So as you can see, vote should be egal to 1...

**Here is my code :**

```
<?php if($data['statut'] == 1) { ?>
 <button type="button" class="button" id="<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>">-1</button><?php 
} else { ?>
 <button type="button" class="button2" id="<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>">+1</button><?php 
} ?>
```

**AJAX :**

```
        $('button').on("click", function test() {
        $(this).off("click");

        var ID = $(this).attr("id");

        if($(this).hasClass('button2')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add.php",
                data: {"ID_oeuvre": ID},
                success: function(html){
                    $("button#"+ID).removeClass("button2").addClass("button").html("-1");
                    $("button#"+ID).on("click", test);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: {"ID_oeuvre": ID},
                success: function(html){
                    $("button#"+ID).removeClass("button").addClass("button2").html("+1");
                    $("button#"+ID).on("click", test);
                }
            });
            $(this).on("click", test);
        };
    });
```

**ADD.PHP**

```
    $requete = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE vote SET nb_vote = nb_vote + 1 WHERE ID_member = :ID_member');
    $requete->execute(array('ID_member' => $member_ID));
    $requete->closeCursor();
```

**DELETE.PHP** is the same as above, just replace *nb_vote + 1* with *nb_vote - 1*

This problem only happens when I don't reload the page. If I reload the page after each click on the button, there is no problem. So I think that the problem is due to the fact that since there is no page reloading, nb_vote kept the old value but that doesn't explain why it goes back to 0 after that...

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra event listener binded by

```
$(this).on("click", test);
```

it's in the `else` clause. If you open network page in firebug, you should see duplicate requests.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how I could have missed it ! Thank you for your answer sir !